# How to send more than one value to my MQTT Broker

Tags: mqtt, microcontroller, esp32, micropython, mpu6050

I am using an ESP32 microcontroller to read data via the sensor MPU6050.

I am sending the data directly to my MQTT broker and then to a database (using Node-red).

My Question is, how can I send 100 values at once to the broker?

I tried the `time.sleep` but then only one value is published every 1 second. I want that e.g. every 10 seconds the values to be published, like a batch of values are published.

Code:

```py
from umqttsimple import MQTTClient

i2c= SoftI2C(scl=Pin(21), sda=Pin(22))
mpu= mpu6050.accel(i2c)


client = MQTTClient(b"bruecke", mqtt_server, 1883, user=mqtt_username, password=mqtt_password)
client.connect()
    

while True:
    werte= mpu.get_values()
    
    print(werte['AcY'])
    client.publish(topic, str(werte['AcY']))
    time.sleep(1)
                   
print(werte['AcY'])
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75793493/edit) the question to show your code, without knowing what you are currently doing it's not possible to tell you what to change.

Comment: The message body is binary so you can send whatever you want (deciding how to encode the data is up to you). For instance you might decide to send a comma delimitated string (e.g. "123,456,321,231"). Please clarify what you want to send; multiple different readings returned from one call to `get_values()` or the same value from multiple calls (e.g. call `get_values()` every second, store the result, and only send a message when you have 10 results).

Comment: The sensor receives more than 100 values per second. I want to publish eg. 10 values at once to the broker. So whenever the sensor mesured 100 values it should publish.

Comment: Then you write code which publishes every 10 values or 100 values or whatever it is you need, and you decide as @Brits said how to represent that. Are you asking us to write the code for you?

Comment: okay, thank you all!  This is my code and it works:                                                
werte= mpu.get_values()
# Create an array 
data_array = []
for i in range(10):
    data_array.append(str(werte['AcY'])) # Add values to the array

    for werte in data_array:
        werte= mpu.get_values()
        message = str(werte['AcY'])
               
client.publish(topic, str(data_array)) #publish
print(data_array)

Comment: Please don't past code into the comments (it's unreadable). Edit the question instead. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read a certain number of values over a certain period of time, read them at equal intervals while storing them locally. esp32 has 520kb ram and much more rom. i believe you can make a datatype of an array or object to store. after a time lapse publish this data. you can write a separate piece of code for this as it sends values one by one while in this time-lapse another code reads and stores locally.

Comment: Note: after micropython installed, ESP32 is left with 100kb ram and about 2mb rom, available for user

Comment: Then what i said still applies